# ssl redirect function is not working

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions

I want to redirect when our website is on HTTP to HTTPS: I wrote a function but it is not working. please help me.

```
public function add_header(){
    if($this->current_domain == "http://". $this->domain || $this->current_domain == "https://". $this->domain){
        
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']=="https"){ 

            return true;
        
        } elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
            
            $this->redirect = get_option('ssl-redirect-check');
            
            if ( 'on' === strtolower( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] && strpos( home_url(), 'https' ) == false )) {
                    $ssl_url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
                    wp_redirect($ssl_url, 301);
                    exit();
            }
            if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) {
                    $ssl_url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
                    wp_redirect($ssl_url, 301);
                    exit();
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->redirect == "yes"){
                    $ssl_url = "https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
                    wp_redirect($ssl_url, 301);
                    exit();
            }
        }
    } else {
        Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
        Header( "Location: ". $this->current_domain . $this->uri );
        die();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not doing the redirect on the server level? Meaning in Apache or NGINX

Comment: yes, there is a reason. And I am building a plugin. it is a task for me. can you help me with this?

Comment: Ok, then let's start by asking some questions: "but it is not working" - what does that mean? Which parts are not working? Where are the other **relevant** parts of the class? How is the method being called?

Comment: okay, I edit the post and add class and all functions.

Comment: I asked this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/378719/facing-issue-in-implementing-ssl-redirect-plugin 
this same query 2 days ago. but I didn't get any answer. please check this.